# Android adb stop foreground service

Tags: android, service, location, foreground-service

I am working on an app that tracks user location and, on some devices and Android versions, it seems the foreground service used to get the location updates, gets killed.

I have read some other similar questions, and so far the only way to mitigate this would be to use START_STICKY with the Service and handle a restart somehow. I wanted to try that, but noticed that there is no command in adb to stop a foreground service. In fact, when I use adb shell services list, it doesn't include the foreground services, despite it is running in the device at the same moment.

Is there a way to stop a foreground service using adb?

Also, is there any other way to block Android from killing a foreground service randomly?

Comment: May this help https://www.sisik.eu/blog/android/adb/killing-current-foreground-app